# ViewController's view's content is not pushed down by navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, cs193p

So I'm in the process of doing the Stanford CS193p course for IOS7 development and just finished lecture 7.
Everything works fine, except for the fact, that my cardgameviewcontroller is not pushed down under the navigation bar.
So if I add my CardViews in the top left corner, they are overlayed by the navigation bar.
Here is my setup:
[image: nib layout]

The CardMatching Scene, is the one my question is about.
As you can see, it contains a view (that is not resizable btw and stretches under the navigation and tab bars).
Now if I add a view via [self.view addSubview:myview], views get added on the top left corner, and are hidden under the navigation bar. As seen here:

[image: nav bar overlapping]

The top left view is initiated with a frame of (0,0).
So my question is, do i have to push down the content programmatically or did i do smth wrong with the layout in interface builder?

Comment: Where do you want to have the view? If you add it to the scrollview, it should be completely visible when scrolling up, due to the contentInset property on the scrollview. Otherwise, if your viewController is set to be "under top bars" in interfacebuilder, you have to set the origin to (0,40) (I believe the navigation bar is that high).

Comment: Btw, (0,0) is not a frame. Frames have an origin and a size, each consisting of two values, like that: {{0,0},{40,40}}. I think you are talking about the origin when you say (0,0).

Comment: @TAKeanice Yeah you are right. The origin of my first CGRect is (0,0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unchek the under top bars ,under bottom bar options as required

[image: Uncheck under top bars ,under bottom bars]

Comment: This will switch off scrolling under the navigation bar as well!

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice. I will think of this thread when adding scroll views.

Comment: And one more thing; if working with auto layout, there is a top layout guide, which is pushed down by the navigation bar.

Comment: You've made my day.. Thanks!

Comment: @Scaryguy Glad it helped!